# Regular expression validator for an eight digit long number starting with 1

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I know I can use `[Required]`, `[StringLength]` annotations for validating empty string and length requirements but would like to use same regular expression for validating them as well. I haven't tried as I am not very good on regex.

Regular Expression should validate

1.Empty string (should not be allowed)

2.Length of characters (8)

3.Integer

4.Starting number (should be 1)

Here is the code:

```
 [DisplayName("Account Number:")]
 [RegularExpression("", 
             ErrorMessage = "An eight digit long number starting with 1 required")]
 public string accountNo { get; set; }
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this regular expression  `^1\d{7}$`

or

```
^1[0-9]{7}$
```

or, in a crunch,

```
  ^1[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$
```

Sample code:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 Regex RegexObj = new Regex(@"^1\d{7}$");
 bool  result=   RegexObj.IsMatch("" );
```

--result has false value

If you don't want to allow empty string then put following attribuite on the field.

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight my requirement is not to allow empty strings.

Comment: I used `^1\d{7}$` but it lets empty/space to go through.

Comment: Please check the post, this regular expression returns false for empty string.

Comment: I am not sure why but ModelState.IsValid is true for empty string. However it validates spaces from server side (ie; when if I enter a space then ModelState.IsValid is false). Other than that it works. Is there any difference of using regex in data annotations? Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you check results once setting a valid value then setting an empty string.

Comment: 12345678 allowed and then empty string also allowed. strange. All other combinations are properly validated as expected.

Comment: Use [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)] in the attributes and try.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), an empty string always passes the regular expression validator and you should use a required attribute if you want to make sure they entered something.  Alternately, you can derive your own custom data annotation attribute from the regular expression one and handle the empty condition yourself, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure an empty string is valid, add a `[Required]` attribute with `AllowEmptyStrings` set to `true`. This prevents `null` from being assigned, but allows empty strings.

As for the regular expression, Romil's expression should work fine.

```
[DisplayName("Account Number:")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
[RegularExpression(@"^1\d{7}$", 
         ErrorMessage = "An eight digit long number starting with 1 required")]
public string accountNo { get; set; }
```

**EDIT** If you also want to *prevent* empty strings from being validated, simply leave out the `AllowEmptyStrings` settings (as it defaults to `false`).

```
[DisplayName("Account Number:")]
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^1\d{7}$", 
         ErrorMessage = "An eight digit long number starting with 1 required")]
public string accountNo { get; set; }
```

Comment: I don't need to allow empty strings. Empty strings should not be allowed.

Comment: Then just leave out the `AllowEmptyStrings` setting. I found your question to be a bit ambiguous as to what you meant with "validating empty strings". Anyhow, answer's updated.

Comment: Ye, I said I would like to use all of the validations in a single expression. Thanks for answering. Now it looks as same as Romil's answer. Even that does not validate for empty/spaces...